# menubar (not contextual action bar) with navigation

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to design the UI as follows

[image]

In this Horizontal Scrolling Menu,

1. On Select of each Main Menu Item (M1 to M9) I have to update the Sub Menu
2. First Item will be selected by default in Sub Menu
3. "Selected Sub Menu Item" detail will be displayed in "Display Area"

I thought of using fregments, with this I have done 2nd and 3rd point, but don't know how to achieve 1st point. So i have stopped this.

How to design this UI with the mentioned behaviour? Help me to solve this

Comment: Looks like a perfect use case for Fragments: Top Bar, Sub Menu and Display Area. For the 1st point, I suggest to pass a different key to the SubMenu Fragment. Basing on that key, it would load a different layout (or the same layout, but with different strings).

Comment: can you please tell me whats that "key" to pass submenu? are you refering to "unique id" which we can pass through an Intent? or something else?

Comment: Yes, an integer is enough.

Comment: i think this approach works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> **1. On Select of each Main Menu Item (M1 to M9) I have to update the Sub**
>   Menu

You'll need :

1. [**`NavigationDrawer`**](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) for *SubMenu*.
2. [**`TabLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout) for *M1 to Mn*.
3. [**`Fragment`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment)s for displaying contents in *Display Area*.

You also have few options to replace/change the SubMenu:

1. Whenever `Fragment` changes, get the *key or id* of the current Fragment, then change the SubMenu as you need.
2. [Get the current Fragment instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager) and update/change the SubMenu.

And the other method...

> **2. First Item will be selected by default in Sub Menu**

Of course, you can set any item you want to be selected as default. Or:

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

> 3. **Selected Sub Menu Item" detail will be displayed in "Display Area**

It sure it will. You'll just need to replace your `Fragment`.

---

Changing the SubMenu in my suggested case will not be a difficult thing to do:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072760/4409113

Replacing `Fragment`:

[Replace one fragment with an another fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571579/replace-one-fragment-with-an-another-fragment)

You can start with this example of `NavigationDrawer`, `TabLayout` and `Fragments`:

https://github.com/LinX64/AndroidSupportDesign-TabLayout

Comment: few doubts, this app is for smart tv, is this possible to use navigationdrawer? and whenever if we select main menu item first it should update submenu and depending on focus change in submenu, display area will be changing, so i have tried the above sample app to apply focus change without success. All user interaction will be done using RCU

Comment: That depends on your expect of the app, that example was just for beginning. You can even customize it by a customized layout or similiar without using `NavigationDrawer`.